# No moduled named google during Kivy to apk with Buildozer

Tags: android, google-sheets, kivy, apk, buildozer

Her my main.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen,FadeTransition   
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    stored_data = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(Screen,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs),
        self.stored_data = JsonStore('data.json')

def gonder(self):
        name = self.ids.name.text

        scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
                 "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

        creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)
        client = gspread.authorize(creds)
        sheet = client.open("verigonder").sheet1
        sheet.append_row([name])

class ThirdWindow(Screen):
    pass
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class mainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("my.kv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainApp().run()
```

and buildozer.spec requirements is here

```
requirements = python3,kivy,gspread,oauth2client,google-auth-oauthlib,httplib2,pyasn1,pyasn1-modules,rsa,request,google
```

and log of debug

```
06-02 15:25:27.121 25609 25949 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
06-02 15:25:27.121 25609 25949 I python  :    File 
"/home/ademberkaksoy/sheet/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 8, in <module>
06-02 15:25:27.121 25609 25949 I python  :    File 
"/home/ademberkaksoy/sheet/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python- 
installs/myapp/gspread/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
06-02 15:25:27.121 25609 25949 I python  :    File 
"/home/ademberkaksoy/sheet/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python- 
installs/myapp/gspread/auth.py", line 12, in <module>
06-02 15:25:27.121 25609 25949 I python  :  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
06-02 15:25:27.121 25609 25949 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

it is still giving same error. What I need to do for fix this situation? Its working on laptop, but it doesnt work on android because of this error. I thinks its all about the gspread but where is the problem why is still giving this error ?

Comment: Have you installed the libraries required for GSpread to work? Check your gspread installation, and check you have the google-api-python-client installed too. Run `pip install google-api-python-client`.

Comment: Do i have to do this? Because its buildozer error. Its working on a computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: Add `google-auth` to your existing `requirements` of your `buildozer.spec`

Long story:

Yes buildozer/p4a can't do automatic package dependency resolution by default yet.

So the way we want to debug this is by finding ourselves which package is missing.
From the stacktrace check this part:

```
06-02 15:25:27.121 25609 25949 I python  :    File 
"/home/ademberkaksoy/sheet/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python- 
installs/myapp/gspread/auth.py", line 12, in <module>
06-02 15:25:27.121 25609 25949 I python  :  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

And then see for the `gspread` package and `auth` module what exactly it's trying to import. Check that from the source code: https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/v3.6.0/gspread/auth.py#L12

```py
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
```

So now we need to see on which package the `Credentials` class is being defined.
There're multiple ways to find that, but since we know it must be a dependency we check the `setup.py` of that same package.
https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/v3.6.0/setup.py#L46-L50

```py
    install_requires=[
        'requests>=2.2.1',
        'google-auth>=1.12.0',
        'google-auth-oauthlib>=0.4.1'
    ],
```

Here we see 3 dependencies to look from. We could then search further to see if that class is defined in one of them. But actually there're dependencies we would need no matter what. So we can simply add them to then `buildozer.spec` and then `buildozer android clean` and `buildozer android debug`.
That should be it.

But if we're curious still here's where it's really defined https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/v1.16.0/google/oauth2/credentials.py#L50 then checking that project README we see it indeed comes from the `google-auth` package.